Launching “We’ll Be in Touch” as a new Stack Overflow Podcast series
I wanted to announce a fun new project I’ve been working on with the Stack Overflow Content Team to launch a new podcast series.  We’re launching a new show called "We’ll Be in Touch," focusing on developer interviews and career development.  Each episode is roughly in the format of a developer interview, asking guests about their background, current projects, bugs they worked on last week, etc.
For those who haven’t seen me poking around Meta lately getting the necromancer badge on old bug reports, I’m Kyle Mitofsky, a senior developer here on the Public Platform. I’ve been a developer for over a decade, and at Stack for coming up on 3 years, and I’ve always really enjoyed getting to learn more about other developers through interviews, especially without all the stress that comes with an actual interview.  My lukewarm take is that one of the reasons developer interviews are so stressful is because they’re such a mysterious black box.  So hopefully we can have some fun, learn about interesting people, and also shed some light on common interview questions and themes.
We’re kicking off the series by chatting with one of my former co-workers, Yaakov Ellis, currently a Staff Engineer at Intuit, and former staff member and Community Advocate.  I hope you’ll give it a listen and come back with any questions or suggestions you might have for future episodes.
I’ll leave you with this, the sign off for every episode

Thanks for your time, and we’ll be in touch

Or as Yaakov would put it

New podcast debuts
Developers share their paths
On "We'll be in touch"


Will you be featuring workplace.stackexchange.com as the Stack Overflow Podcast does with SO?

If anyone from the community has a suggestion about a post we should highlight, a topic we should cover, or a guest we should invite, please get in touch - podcast at stackoverflow dot com

Thanks Kyle. You were a great teammate, and are a very good friend, and it was fun to have this conversation together.

Please try to listen
on your commute or your walk…
maybe learn something?

